# SwiftUI View - initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I have List in one view and upon selection of a row, would like to navigate to another View. I am trying to pass 'LocationInfra', a coredata entity to another ConfigProfileView. I get two errors in the SummaryView, when I call ConfigProfileView via NavigationLink

'ConfigProfileView' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
Cannot convert value of type 'FetchedResults.Element' (aka 'LocationInfra') to expected argument type 'Binding<LocationInfra?>'

```
struct summaryView: View {
 @State public var selectedLocationInfra: LocationInfra? = nil
   var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
             ForEach(locationProfiles) { locationProfile in
                 NavigationLink (""){
                   ConfigProfileView(locationInfra: selectedLocationInfra) // get two errors here
                 }
                 label: do {
                   HStack {
                     // some code here
                   }.onTapGesture {
                            selectedLocationInfra = locationProfile
                }

             }
        }
    }
     .navigationTitle("Summary")
  }

}
```

view to be displayed

```
 struct ConfigProfileView: View {
   @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
   @Binding private var locationInfra: LocationInfra? 

    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack (alignment: .leading ) {
                 Text(locationInfra?.locationName!)
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

How to fix the errors?

Comment: I don't get it. Is your purpose just to pass a single element from locationProfiles (an LocationInfra array) to ConfigProfileView without changing it, right?

Comment: Yes single LocationInfra element from the array. I save it in .onTapGesture

Comment: why can you make it simple like `var locationInfra: LocationInfra?` in `ConfigProfileView`, then pass through right inside `ForEach`?. I mean you knew the array, knew the index, use it directly.

Comment: You could try using `@Binding var locationInfra: LocationInfra?` in `ConfigProfileView` and
 `ConfigProfileView(locationInfra: $selectedLocationInfra)` in `SummaryView`, note the `$`, note also `NavigationView` is deprecated use `NavigationStack`.

Comment: @son. If I do that I get error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)

Comment: @workingdog support Ukraine - If I do that I still get error: 'ConfigProfileView' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

Comment: are you sure you used `@Binding var locationInfra: LocationInfra?` without the `private`? In any case show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I debugger I get error: 'ConfigProfileView' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection leve
'init(appDelegate:defaults:locationInfra:)' declared here
I dont know what the second error means?

Comment: @vrao so weird, can you check code below?

Comment: Yes, I used. @Binding var locationInfra: LocationInfra?. Now I am getting error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)

Comment: @son I did that, error is gone. When I tap on the row the .onTapGesture is called, but NavigationLink is not called.

Comment: @vrao navigation is tappable itself, you should remove .onTapGesture like the below code.

Comment: @son when I do that  gives error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call, insert '<#LocalizedStringKey#>' on the line where I call NavigationLink. So I changed it to look like NavigationLink("ConfigProfile") {  ConfigProfileView(locationInfra: locationProfile)} then it creates a link inside each row  called ConfigProfile and when I press that it navigates to ConfigProfileView. However pressing the row by itself, does not invoke navigation at all. I want to press the row (identified by disclosure indicator >)and invoke navigation. Is that possible?

Comment: NavigationLink needs also title or label as an argument. So, `NavigationLink("ConfigProfile")` or `NavigationLink { ... } label: { Text("ConfigProfile") }` is equivalent. What do you mean "does not invoke navigation at all" after "I press that it navigates to ConfigProfileView".

Comment: When I press the navigationlink 'configProfile' it navigates prefectly. In old Swift I could have a disclosure indicator and in a method cellForRowAt, I could handle presenting some other controller. I was thinking if there an equivalent in SwiftUI where I could press on disclosure indicator (without pressing on a navigationlink) and get it to navigate. If not I will disable the disclosure indicator and use the navigationlink from each row. Accepted your answer

Comment: If you do it that way, AFAIK, you should define a @Binding property which passed from outside to determine whenever using NavigationLink or disclosure indicator. Then config ForEach in these 2 cases: 1 case for that custom view with disclosure indicator, and another one is NavigationLink like in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your array could be like this:

```swift
struct SummaryView: View {
    var locationProfiles: [LocationInfra] = [
        .init(index: 0, locationName: "US"),
        .init(index: 1, locationName: "UK"),
        .init(index: 2, locationName: "SG")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(locationProfiles) { locationProfile in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ConfigProfileView(locationInfra: locationProfile)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Index: \(locationProfile.index)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Summary")
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `ConfigProfileView`, just for displaying:

```swift
struct ConfigProfileView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    var locationInfra: LocationInfra?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack (alignment: .leading ) {
                    Text(locationInfra?.locationName ?? "unknown")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]